# How to make an array with its items as another array

Tags: java, arrays

For example I'm making a hangman program and for the words I want to make an array called `words` and the items in words are the letters what ever word

This is what I thought you could do:

```
String[] words =  new String [15];
words[1] = String[] MILK = {"M","I","L","K"};
words[2] = String[] CLOTH = {"C","L","O","T","H"};
```

Comment: Is it possible to place array inside array?

Comment: You might consider using `char` arrays instead, e.g. `{'M', 'I', 'L', 'K'}`.

Comment: I thought JavaScript :) I better remove that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
String[][] words =  new String [15][];
String[] milk = words[0] = new String[] {"M","I","L","K"};
String[] cloth = words[1] = new String[] {"C","L","O","T","H"};
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use array of arrays

```
String[][] arrays = new String[][] { array1, array2,  array53};
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called a multidimensional array. These are basically arrays inside of arrays.

Your code should be as follows:

```
String[][] words =  new String [15][];
words[1] = new String[] {"M","I","L","K"};
words[2] = new String[] {"C","L","O","T","H"};
```

For documentation on it, see [this website](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you will be using is a two dimensional array.

Think of it as a matrix that will look something like this

```
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```

Where each box contains a letter.

You initialize by using the following code

```
String[][] words =  new String [x][y];
```

Where x is the total number of words (rows) and y is the total number of letters (columns).